# calculate the difference between 2 values in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a table displaying values:

- 1st column: date
- 2, 3, 4 column: name of magazines.

The date column shows today's date and columns 2,3,4 display a number of how many subscriptions there are for each magazine. Every day the numbers change and a mysql query fetches the numbers from the database and displays them in the table.

I would like to display a row showing the difference between 2 consecutive days ie how much the subscription to a particular magazine when up/down: `Todays value - yesterdays value`.

The query I am running is in a `foreach` loop. How would I calculate consecutive values?

My code is:

```
    foreach($values as $v_date){
$date = $v_date->DATE; 

  $count = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    " SELECT DISTINCT `date`,
    (select subscriber_count FROM wp_email_signup where LIST_NAME = 'B1' AND date = '$date') as 'B1',
    (select subscriber_count FROM wp_email_signup where LIST_NAME = '2D' AND date = '$date' ) as '2D',
    (select subscriber_count FROM wp_email_signup where LIST_NAME = 'F90' AND date = '$date' ) as 'F90'
        FROM wp_email_signup WHERE date = '$date' "));
echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';
foreach($count as $counts){
  $val1 =  $counts->B1;
  $val2 = $counts->2D;
  $val3 = $counts->F90; 
        echo '<td>' . $val1 . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $val2 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $val3 . '</td>';  


        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr class="row_diff">';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td>' . DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 2 CONSECUTIVE VALUES . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 2 CONSECUTIVE VALUES . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 2 CONSECUTIVE VALUES. '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd probably do this in SQL The performance can't be worse than what you have now (hammering the database with several queries instead of asking for a date range in one query).

Comment: could you recommend a better SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work.

```
// set some values to zero so that our subtraction does not produce errors
$prev1 = 0;
$prev2 = 0;
$prev3 = 0;

foreach($count as $counts)
{
    $val1 =  $counts->B1;
    $val2 = $counts->2D;
    $val3 = $counts->F90;

    echo '<td>' . $val1 . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $val2 . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $val3 . '</td>';  

    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr class="row_diff">';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td>' . ($val1 - $prev1) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . ($val2 - $prev2) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . ($val3 - $prev3) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    // Set the current loop of values to be subtracted for the next loop
    $prev1 = $val1;
    $prev2 = $val2;
    $prev3 = $val3;
}
```